# corverting null to 0

Tags: jasper-reports

i tried to do this,

(case when (PREPAYMENT_AMT != null) then 0 else (PREPAYMENT_AMT) END)

why its still apper null???

Comment: can somebody tell me why variable appear null in group band? im stuck for 3 weeks already....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know in SQL, null is not equal to anything because it is the unknown value. How can one unknown equal another? It makes no sense. There are special operators to deal with null.

```
(case when (PREPAYMENT_AMT IS NULL) then 0 else (PREPAYMENT_AMT) END)
```

There are also functions in most SQL languages to do what you want. In MS SQL Server, `ISNULL(PREPAYMENT_AMT, 0)` will do what you want. In MySQL, it's `COALESCE(PREPAYMENT_AMT, 0)`.

You should know that I don't know what ireport is, so check your docs for how to handle nulls.

Comment: (case when (PREPAYMENT_AMT IS NULL) then 0 else (PREPAYMENT_AMT) END) successfully converting null to 0 in iReport

Answer (score 0):

Because you're changing it to 0 if it's NOT null. You need AMT == null

Comment: i have tried (case when (PREPAYMENT_AMT = null) then 0 else (PREPAYMENT_AMT) END) but still it appear null

Comment: The single equals "=" assigns a variable. To check for equality you need the double equals "==". This is a common mistake for beginners, and one we've all made.

Comment: ive tried "==" earlier but there is an error "missing expression"

Comment: Then you have an error somewhere else, because "==" is what you need for comparison. Can you post some more of the code?